# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject

Tags: android-ndk

```
public class MyOpaqueBasedJSONDict implements IMyJSONDict {

    private final long _myNativeCPPObj;
...

public IMyJSONDict getMyJSONObj(String keyName) {
        long retVal = nativeGetJSOBObject(_myNativeCPPObj,keyName);
        return (new MyOpaqueBasedJSONDict(retVal));
    }

native implementation
NIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_com_hexample_myndkapplication_MyOpaqueBasedJSONDict_nativeGetJSOBObject(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                             jobject instance,
                                                                             jlong myNativeCPPObj,
                                                                             jstring keyName_) {
    const char *keyName = env->GetStringUTFChars(keyName_, 0);

    Json::Value* nativeCppJson_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Json::Value*> (myNativeCPPObj);

    Json::Value& map = *nativeCppJson_ptr;

    Json::Value& jsonVal = map[keyName];
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(keyName_, keyName);
    return (jlong) &jsonVal;
}
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0xb4019a80
>   08-16 03:25:56.785 20537-20537/com.hexample.myndkapplication A/art:
>   art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from long
>   com.hexample.myndkapplication.MyOpaqueBasedJSONDict.nativeGetJSOBObject

Any clue how to debug invalid memory errors in ndk. I am pretty new to Android and ndk development.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was the incoming `const char * str` parameter that was not playing ball with the `CallStaticVoidMethod`. To fix this we have to create a new `jstring` and pass that back to Java instead:

```
// str is a const char *
jstring x = env->NewStringUTF(str);
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jclassMainClass, methodId, x);
env->DeleteLocalRef(x);
```

Makes sense really since JNI bridges C++ and Java and Java will only accept a Java string (`jstring`) not a `const char *`, despite passing the latter not causing a compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case,I used jobject in multi native thread:

```
javaCallBackObj = env->NewGlobalRef(jobj);
```

> Note however that the jclass is a class reference and must be protected with a call to NewGlobalRef (see the next section).
> [Andorid Jni doc](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#jclass,-jmethodid,-and-jfieldid)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I was calling the native function with the rigth arguments but wrong return type

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem in my android app. Further I found that the String argument is the "invalid jobject" mentioned by JNI. I tried input non-empty string as argument and the error gone. I don't know why it's that. I hope that it can help you as workaround.

Comment: I removed the string argument and there was no crash, so it's definitely the string for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue too,the situation is using wrong .so file .It should be x86 but I used x86_64.